# fetch returns first empty array, after that it returns response

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I'm making my final degree project and now I'm involved in the part to show towns on a map using data from a backend URL.

The problem is that fetch returns at first an empty array, and I need it to stay loading until the variable is a valid JSON.

```
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);

    const getTowns = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/towns`);
            const json = await response.json();
            setMarkers(json.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getTowns();
    }, []);
```

Another question is: Why when I put a console.log('whatever') it appears more than one time on the console. Don't understand why

What I need is fetch to setLoading(false) only when response is a JSON, not an empty array

Comment: Still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add these 2 hooks to your code:

- A state for the returned response (with initial value an empty array)
- A useEffect which will set to false isLoading once the response state change value

```js
const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

const getTowns = async () => {
    try {
        setResponse(() => await fetch(`${baseUrl}/towns`));
        const json = await response.json();
        setMarkers(json.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(() => false);
}, [response]);
```

Comment: Hi, that didnt work for me. It says "response.json is not a function. (In 'response.json()', 'response.json' is undefined)":

Here you can see the full code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EeUYk8G6vdujGXX4tqx23Qe8CH7wmnM-bx1uoaWuChs/edit?usp=sharing